# SQlite or Shared Preferences

Tags: android, sqlite, sharedpreferences

In my android app I receive data as json like this:

```
    "_playLists":[{"name":"Playlist 1",

    "items":[{"name":"Poza 1","target":"...","url":"...","url_thumb":"..."},

    {"name":"Poza 2","target":"http:\/\/audifrance.fr","url":"...","url_thumb":..."}]},


    {"name":"Playlist 2",
    "items":[{"name":"Poza 3","target":"...","url":null,"url_thumb":null}]}]}
```

My question is : which is the best way to save data from this response: using Shared Preferences or using a database SQlite? Is it possible using Shared Preferences to make connections between the saved data?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If there is **no security concern** with data, **data is complex type** and **data is in large amount** I think `SQLite is the best for it`.

And if **the data is small**, **data is premitive type** and **you don't want to share it with user** then `SharedPreference is good.`

Choice is yours.. Thanks.

Comment: Hi do you can explain the security concern with the SQLite ,Is it not safe to store data in SQLite ? I want to know do i lose my data from shared pref in any way other than uninstalling the app

Answer (score 3):

both have different purposes .

for small sized primitive data's where you don't want to invoke any queries use shared preferences .

for large sized , complex type storage , use sqLite